# Reading a Float Line from a File W/o Knowing Its Length

Tags: octave

I am relatively new to octave, so my question is: how can I read each line containing numbers from a file without knowing their length?

Line lengths vary.

I only know how many lines there are.

Each line has two or more float values, so I can't use "fgetl" because that will mean I will get a string, but I need an array.

Comment: Are the numbers delimited in some way? For example, is there a space or a comma between them?

Comment: Yes, there is a space between them. Example: -9.5 9 5 6 -5 7 6 3

Comment: I suggest you use fgetl, and then parse each line using your own logic.

Comment: Thank you! I was hoping there would be some kind of function, but I guess I have to do all the work. :(

Answer (score 1):

There are many options and depends hoe you want to have your data stored. One way:

yourfile:

```
3.14 5.2 6.4
1.2 8.4
9.2
10.5 12.4
```

The code

```
fid = fopen ("yourfile", "r");
while ((tmp = fgetl (fid)) != -1)
  C = strread (tmp, "%f")
  #process C here
endwhile
fclose (fid);
```

gives:

```
C =

   3.1400
   5.2000
   6.4000

C =

   1.2000
   8.4000

C =  9.2000
C =

   10.500
   12.400
```